# Interval Joda Time

Tags: jodatime, intervals

I have a problema with my code. I hope you can help me.

Its about the intervals of Joda Time.

My problem is:

When I wanna know if the date is between two dates and the date is equals to the end date the bucle is infinite. Can't find the match when the date is equals to the end date.

Ex:

```
while (!comprobar) {

            Interval interval = new Interval("2025-02-24",
                    "2025-02-28");

            if (interval.contains("2025-02-28") || interval.equals("2025-02-28")) {
                comprobar = true;
            }


            if (!comprobar) {
                i++;
            }

        }

        if (comprobar) {
            int res = mapHoras.get(i) - hor;
            mapHoras.put(i, res);
            // mapFestivos.remove(dt);

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: The expression `new Interval("2025-02-24", "2025-02-28")`  does not even compile! It appears you want a plain date interval, but Joda-Time only offers instant-intervals so you have to simulate some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the javadoc of [org.joda.time.Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html):

> A time interval represents a period of time between two instants.
>   Intervals are inclusive of the start instant and exclusive of the end.

The end date is excluded by definition, so you have to check for equality of the end date.

```
if (interval.contains(date) || interval.getEnd().equals(date)) {...}
```